# getting item that is focused on in a listwiew using th up and down arrow key

Tags: c#, listview, selecteditem, keydown, keyup

I wish to get the selected item from a listview, but not by clicking on it as i already have a function that does this. I will like to use my up and down arrow to do this.

I have already got a method but it throws an exception, can anyone help to refactor this? here is the method below

```
private void lvViewFile_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    ListView lvTemp = (ListView)sender;
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
    {
        if (lvTemp.Focused == true)
        {
            var selected = this.lvCategory.SelectedItems[0].Focused;
        }
    }
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
    {
        if (lvTemp.Focused == true)
        {
            var selected = this.lvCategory.SelectedItems[0].Focused;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: On what line and what type of exception you get? `NullReferenceException` on this line `var selected = this.lvCategory.SelectedItems[0].Focused;`?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do just what i want.

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
{
    if (lvTemp.Focused == true)
    {
        var selected = lvTemp.FocusedItem.Index;
        if (selected.Equals(0))
        {
            enableMoveDown();
        }
        else if (selected.Equals(lvCategory.Items.Count - 1))
        {
            enableMoveUp();
        }
        else
        {
            enableMoveUpMoveDown();
        }
    }
}
else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
{
    if (lvTemp.Focused == true)
    {
        var selected = lvTemp.FocusedItem.Index;
        if (selected.Equals(0))
        {
            enableMoveDown();
        }
        else if (selected.Equals(lvCategory.Items.Count - 1))
        {
            enableMoveUp();
        }
        else
        {
            enableMoveUpMoveDown();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An old post, but I adapted the accepted answer to display data from a database when using arrow keys to navigate a ListView. This may be helpful to others:

```
ListView lv = sender as ListView;
if (lv.Focused) // which it should be as the user is running arrow keys on it!
{
    int selected = lv.FocusedItem.Index; // gets the index of the CURRENT ListViewItem (Not the one you see highlighted after arrow key movement)
    switch (e.KeyCode) // Can use if/else here if preferred
    {
        case Keys.Up:
            //Change index to the row above the current one
            selected--;
            if(selected < 0) //check if already on the first row
            {
                selected = 0;
            }
            break;
        case Keys.Down:
            //Change index to the row below the current one
            selected++;
            if(selected > lv.Items.Count - 1) //check if index out of range
            {
                selected = lv.Items.Count - 1;
            }
            break;
    }
    // Carry out your choice of action. (This one reads a database and fills fields)
    FillFields(lvClients.Items[selected].SubItems[0].Text);
}
```